# Getting I/O error 104 when reading a text file

Tags: delphi

I'm getting a I/O error 104 when reading `TP` (a file containing a Picture name):

```
procedure TfrmAvatar.FormShow(Sender: TObject);
var
  sLocation: String;
  TU, TP: textfile;
  sUser: string;
  iTemp: integer;
begin
  sLocation := ExtractFileDir(ExtractFileDir(ExtractFileDir(ParamStr(0))));
  AssignFile(TU, (sLocation + '\Username.txt'));
  Reset(TU);
  Readln(TU, sUser);
  edtUser.Text := sUser;
  CloseFile(TU);

  AssignFile(TP, (sLocation + '\Profile.txt'));
  Reset(TP);
  Readln(TU, sUser);  //Getting 104 here on read
  ShowMessage(sLocation + sUser);
 
  imgAvatar.Picture.LoadFromFile(sLocation + sUser);
  CloseFile(TP);
end;
```

Like I said above, I'm simply reading one line from an assigned file `TP`. I don't see where my mistake is. If it is obvious, just let me know.

Comment: It's time to stop using legacy pascal I/O and move to streams and writers/readers

Comment: We have no choice other than legacy Pascal I/O since that is what we are being taught to use as such it is necessary to use it in our PATs.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You are reading from a closed file handle (`TU`).
What you want to do is

```
readln(TP, suser);
```

Comment: I am so dumb haha how did I not notice this and after retyping it all from start to finish 3 times thank you

Comment: @Protoyp8 Since you are using only 1 TextFile at a time, you don't need 2 TextFile  variables. Then you wouldn't have run ino this problem in the first place.